# How to annotate with Values and "text" in the same string: ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add an annotation with "text" followed by a value to a plot made with ggplot2. I can add text with:

```
annotate("text", x = 40, y = 8, label = "EXAMPLE")
```

and can add a value with:

```
VALUE <- coef(FUNCTION)[2]
annotate("text", x = 41.5, y = 8, label = VALUE)
```

I can make them appear in line with the following code but it seems tedious

```
annotate("text", x = 40, y = 8, label = "EXAMPLE") + 
  annotate("text", x = 41.5, y = 8, label = FUNCTION)
```

Comment: Use `paste` to stick the strings you need together

Comment: Would that look something like this:  annotate("text", x = 40, y = 8, label = paste("EXAMPLE ": FUNCTION))

Comment: It might. I don't know for sure without seeing the data you're working with